# Can not import maven project to IDEA 14

Tags: macos, maven, intellij-idea

I do `$ mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=demo -DartifactId=demo` to create a maven project

then I want import the project to IDEA 14

[image]

then I choose `Import project from external model` and `maven` to next.

then there are some option we need to do , I just click `next`.

then it tells me to `Select Maven projects to import`

but there is nothing to show.

please tell me how to create a maven project and how to import it to IDEA 14 .

Comment: Looks like you did not turn on the recursive search....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I always just `Open` project by selecting its `pom.xml` and it works well every time. Try this instead of `Import Project`.

Comment: For a generally useful product Intellij has more bugs than anything else I've encountered. This is a good example. E.g File|Open on the directory may work or may not. Roll the dice.,

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem today. Tried many times. Finally, I got the solution that just to kill all the IntelliJ processes, restart it. It works. Seems some memory got corrupted, but please at least show some error message.